# Issue with "Loop through all the sheets" with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

Issue with "Loop through all the sheets" with VBA

I would like to check on all sheets that is there a cell in the 6nd row which contains "text". The code is the following but it does not work. It works only on the active sheet.

```
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            
            For j = 1 To 30
                If Cells(6, j) = "text" Then
                MsgBox (j)
                Else
                End If
            Next j
        
        Next ws
```

If I just for example: range("A1")="Yes" it works on all sheet.

Comment: `ws.cells(6, j)`

Comment: If you don't specify the parent worksheet for `Cells`, it assumes `ActiveSheet` is its parent. Which means it wont change as `ws` iterates through the `Worksheets` collection. As Warcupine pointed out, you need to use `ws` as the parent object for `Cells` so that it changes sheets with the loop. `ws.Cells(6, j)`.